# Unsure what this is displaying

Tags: sql

```
select mvid
from GenreInfo
where genre='Drama' 
and mvid in (
select mvid
from GenreInfo
where genre != 'Drama');
```

I'm just checking will my code output all movies that are exclusively dramas and all movies that are exclusively not dramas?

Comment: I'm confused... wouldn't the result always be nothing?

Comment: Depends on your table structure, please provide that. Also SO is not really a replacement for unit/integration tests.

Comment: @Mithir no if `mvid` is not a primary key/unique I believe.

Comment: Have you tried it? What did it display?

Comment: The table being used is GenreInfo(MVID,GENRE).

Comment: I did try it and then tested it against two other forms.

Comment: @AndreyShchekin - You are right, so it will return only the movies which are not exclusively dramas. meaning, the genre is at least drama, and 1 or more genres.

Answer (score 2):

Your query will give you the movies that is `Drama` and at least one other genre.
It will not return the movies that are exclusively `Drama`.

Answer (score 0):

If every mvid can only have one genre then what you want is the same as extract every film in the table!

```
SELECT mvid FROM GenreInfo WHERE genre = 'Drama' OR genre <> 'Drama'
```

is the same as:

```
SELECT mvid FROM GenreInfo
```

Comment: Thats exactly what i thought, however, its outputting mvid 1-6 then jumping to 11, 14, 15, 17. So some movies are being skipped.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question! If you use the SELECT in your QUESTIONS maybe you obtain these results because every film can have different genres! So you obtain all films that are drama but also another genre.

Comment: Yes you are right, all movies with drama and another genre is printed,Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The result of this query will be nothing (assuming that for every movie there's only one entry) - you're effectively selecting movies that are both drama, and not drama :).

If a movie can have multiple genres assigned, please tell us how it's done. Also, edit your post and tell us what database are you using.

edit: for mvid not unique (works in sql server, but should for other dbs, too):

```
select distinct
    gi.mvid
from GenreInfo gi
where gi.genre='Drama' 
    or not exists (
        select 1 from GenreInfo where mvid=gi.mvid and genre='Drama'
    )
```

Comment: The movie can have multiple genres and that would be assigned like this - 
insert into GenreInfo values(1,'Crime'); 
insert into GenreInfo values(1,'Drama');
I'm using oracle SQL

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the table GenreInfo looks like:

```
        mVid    Genre
         1      Drama
         2      Drama
         2      SciFi
         3      Drama
         3      SciFi
         4      SciFi
```

Your query will return: 2,3

This is because you are essentially saying:
Give me all the mVid's where Genre = Drama (gives 1,2,3)
and also from that list, give me those mVids for which Genre is not Drama (gives 2,3 because they have SciFi also)

**So overall you'll get a list of mVids where Genre is Drama as well as at least one other Genre.**

If you want to get those where Genre is exclusively Drama, then do the following:

```
    SELECT * FROM GenreInfo WHERE Genre = 'Drama' and NOT mVid in (
        SELECT mVid FROM GenreInfo WHERE Genre <> 'Drama'
    )
```